# Product of vector, in order, result is single number based on last product

Tags: r

A vector:

```
y <- c(1.1, 1.05, 1.01)

initial_amount <- 100
```

I would like to multiply initial_amount by the vector in the following way:

```
initial_amount * 1.1 * 1.05 * 1.01
[1] 116.655
```

Suppose I have a vector `y` and `initial_amount` numeric variable. How can I tell r to compute a final amount in this way? Using the example the result would be 116.655

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can create a vector by concatenating the 'initial_amount' with 'y' and use `prod`

```
prod(c(initial_amount, y))
[1] 116.655
```

Or may use `Reduce` with `*`

```
Reduce(`*`, c(initial_amount, y))
[1] 116.655
```